# VueJS - can't get user token from Django Rest Framework via login POST

Tags: vuejs2, axios, django-rest-framework

I have token authentication setup with DRF and VueJS. However, I can't seem to login using the combo of VueJS, axios, and the DRF token system and I don't understand why. I have `CORS` installed and if I manually set the token into the VueJS code, all my requests from VueJS to the DRF backend API work fine. It's just the login and getting the initial token that isn't working.

Here's my code:

**Django URLs:**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
url(r'^api/token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
```

**Django middleware**

```
class SiteLogin:
  def process_request(self, request):
    url = request.path.split('/')

    # Don't require password for the URL /api/token-auth/
    if url[1] == 'api' and url[2] == 'token-auth':
      return None
```

**auth Service -- VueJS:**

```
  // ... other code ...
  login (context, creds, redirect) {
    console.log(creds)
    axios.post(LOGIN_URL, creds).then((response) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
      this.user.authenticated = true

      // If a redirect link is provided
      if (redirect) {
        router.push(redirect)
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  },
```

### Login Component - VueJS:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class='container-fluid container-fullw bg-white'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
          Login<br>
          <br>
          <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder="Username" v-model='credentials.username'><br>
          <input type='password' class='form-control' placeholder="Password" v-model='credentials.password'><br>
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' @click='submit()'>Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import auth from '../../services/auth'

export default {
  name: 'login',
  data () {
    return {
      credentials: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      },
      error: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      auth.login(this, this.credentials, '/')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Upon clicking "Submit" the DRF backend always returns a 401.

**Edit**:

Also, if I add `print(request.POST)` into the `SiteLogin` section of the Django middleware, I can see that a) the `if` statement returns true (it's acknowledging that it's a login URL) and b) the `QueryDict` is empty -- I see: `<QueryDict: {}>`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850775/717682

Problem was that the `TokenAuthentication` was preventing my axios `POST` request from being called at all -- immediately returning a 401.